# Defining a string in an if statement

Tags: c++

Im trying to make a number that is positive (already converted into a string) look like "+number" instead of "number" but i can't define it in an if

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
     std::string x3s;
     int number = 145;
     if (number >= 0)
     {
     x3s = "+" + number;
     }
     std::cout << x3s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I guess you'd be interested to know about [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)?

Comment: If you define a variable inside an `if`then it is visible only inside that block, but not outside of it.

Comment: Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then edit your question to elaborate on your problem, and if the code you show is not an [mcve] of the failing code then please show us the actual failing code.

Comment: Neither `"+"` nor `number` are of type `std::string`.  (`"+"` is a string literal, but is actually represented as an array of two `char`, not a `std::string`).   It is therefore necessary to make the right hand side of the assignment give a result of type `std::string`.   For example, `x3s = "+" + std::to_string(number)`.     The `std::to_string(number)` produces a `std::string` from `number`.   Then there is an `operator+(const char *`, const std::string &)` that can then be called, and produce the result you seek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there is an I/O manipulator `std::showpos`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int number = 145;
    std::cout << std::showpos << number << std::endl;
}
```

Secondly, you are using the verb "define" incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you. Im sorry that im using define wrong, im new to coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `x3s = std::string("+") + std::to_string(number);`

Comment: `std::string` does not have such a ctor but `std::string("+")` works.

Comment: @Hiroki - `std::string` (or more accurately `std::basic_string<char>` which is what `std::string` actually is) does have a constructor that accepts a `const char *`.   A string literal can be passed to that constructor.

Comment: @Hiroki - ISO/IEC 14882, otherwise known as the C++ standard.  In 1998 standard, the fourth constructor listed in Section 21.3.1.  All later standards have the same constructor listed.

Comment: @Peter very thx. But is `'+'` `const char*` ? I think it is `char` and can not be compiled, gcc: https://wandbox.org/permlink/j29QtetXNBRi66xa , clang: https://wandbox.org/permlink/7KLFVp5PMbsKNlNP

Comment: Yeah, okay.   You could have simply pointed out that this answer has a typo, that makes it different from the original question.  I'll edit shortly.